# c# y google traductor

Tags: c#, windows-forms

actualmente tenia que traducir 100 documentos xml, con miles de lineas de texto por documento, así que decidi crear una app que hiciera la traduccion de manera automatica después depuraría los archivos, utilizo c# de windows form, un objeto de tipo webBrowser

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("https://translate.google.com.mx/", System.UriKind.Absolute); //-- inicializo el link
```

//-- funcion que utilizo para traducir

```
private void ActivarAccionInputAsync()
    {
        HtmlElementCollection elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");

        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "er8xn") // busca el text area que utiliza para traducir
            {
                element.SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text); // Reemplaza el texto del text area que google utiliza para traducir

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    //Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
                    //element.Focus();
                    //SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
                }
                element.InvokeMember("paste");
                textBox1.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

cabe mencionar que el código con la función que esta no ejecuta la traducción del texto enviado al textarea que maneja la traducción, ya que requiere que se invoke las funciones de entrada veo que tiene estos atributos:

```
<textarea aria-label="Texto original" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="kvLWu" class="er8xn" jsaction="blur:TP1Wfd; click:R8nDBd; focus:dFlNRb,HCeAxb; input:r9XDpf,Gyn8rd; mouseup:Sxi9L,BR6jm; mousedown:qjlr0e; keydown:O0Dsab; keyup:pHu1gc; paste:puy29d;" jsname="BJE2fc" jslog="176025; track:click,input,paste;" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" role="combobox" rows="1" placeholder="" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

así que asumo que es necesario invocar el evento input, o paste, pero sigue sin traducir, he encontrado una manera de pasarle el foco al elemento del textarea, y ejecutar el comando ctrl + v desde el codigo c# copiar el texto que quiero desde el portapapeles esto hace que la traducción se ejecute, pero eso hace que la traducción sea limitado a esperar que se termine de ejecutar ctrl+v, si alguno tenga una alternativa para poder hacer que el textarea ejecute su funcionamiento de traducir sin tener que utilizar esto, sería de mucha ayuda:

```
Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
element.Focus();
SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
```

Comment: Puedes pasar parámetros en la url: https://translate.google.com/?sl=es&tl=en&text=adi%C3%B3s&op=translate

Comment: si pero eso hace que tengas que reactualizar la url del webview, lo cual lo hace lento y menos efectiva, y lo que se busca es optimizar el procedimiento no alentarlo más de lo que ya es.

Comment: Creo que ni te has dado cuenta de lo que estas intentando hacer. Google tiene una batería de ingenieros del MIT que cobran más de 1 millón de US al año trabajando, entre otras cosas, para que no sea posible hacer lo que tu quieres hacer. Y además tu quieres hacerlo con WinForms y webBrowser y por si fuera poco quieres que sea "efectiva" y "optimizada"....pero vamos!

Comment: Como lo estas planeando va a fallar por todos lados, tienes muchos menos riesgos usando la URL con los parámetros, que se recargue la página y esperar el medio segundo que demora, que en 100 texto es menos de 1 minuto

Comment: pero que locura dices amigo?, esto es posible y muy sencillamente, no fue la gran cosa en realidad, al final envie una script en js para simular el foco y el ctrl + v para que el text area reconozca la acción pegar y se ejecute la traducción al final cumple con lo que necesitaba

Comment: No dije que no era posible, dije que te iba a fallar por todos lados. Cuando lo tengas  productivo un tiempo te vas a dar cuenta.